# Creating VM in VirtualBox from existing Ubuntu installation

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox

I already have Ubuntu set up as a dual boot with Windows 7 x64.

Is there a way to install VirtualBox and create a virtual machine that points to the installed Ubuntu, so I don't have to reinstall Ubuntu? I currently have Ubuntu on my second hard drive.

This will be my first time using VirtualBox. I have used VMWare Fusion on my prior Macs, so know a little about VMs. Or would it be better to uninstall and start from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [VMWare Converter](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/info/slug/infrastructure_operations_management/vmware_vcenter_converter_standalone/5_0?amp;amp;rls=com.microsoft:*&amp;ie=UTF-8&amp;oe=UTF-8&amp;startIndex=&amp;startPage=1&hl=en&sa=X&nfpr=&spell=1) to build a VMDK of your Linux system.  From there you can import the VMDK into a VirtualBox instance.  Detailed instructions are available at [SYSPROBS](http://www.sysprobs.com/physical-virtual-virtualbox-virtualbox-p2v).

Answer (score 1):

You can configure VirtualBox to access a raw partition or disk. This functionality isn't exposed in the GUI, but https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#rawdisk shows how to do it from the command line. A Ubuntu install is fairly hardware agnostic, and should boot normally within a VM, If you have any trouble, try making sure the fstab entries are specified by GUID instead of devicename, in case the device names are different between VirtualBox and running directly.